# Formula to convert vertical force into horizontal force to determine the needed torque of a motor?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

I am a very uneducated individual with maybe 3rd grade level math skills. Say I want to build a rotating camera mount and I need to specify the proper torque/motor to accomplish the task. How would I convert the vertical force (gravity/the weight of the camera and the arm) in pounds into the torque of motor I need. Basically, it is a 90° difference in the directions. Is there a formula to convert vertical weight into sideways 90° torque weight?

I imagine their are some variables like distance from the axis that matter/weight of the arm, and so on. I tried to think of them all and map them out in this really rough diagram but I may have missed some. Please explain to me in a very basic way what this formula is.

[image: 1]

Comment: Torque is just the force times the distance. So the force (weight) times how long the arm is. Multiply Newtons times meters. Force is mass times 9.82 (gravity).

Comment: @NateSire but it will not be the full force of the object, it will be the torque required to overcome the friction in the bearing and the moment of inertia of the camera on the arm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job of the motor torque isn't to resist gravity or the weight of the payload (camera). This job falls onto the motor bearing and the design of the axle.

However, the axle is allowed to rotate it is going to need some torque to turn due to friction and the overturning moment created by the camera.

Ideally, to minimize this effect, you are going to need to counterweight the payload such that the combined center of mass is on the axis of the motor. This way the motor torque is only required to overcome the friction to turn the axle

By your design, the motor must resist the following loading. Consider the example rotation speed $n = 100\,\mathrm{rpm}$ . Also consider the center of mass is located at $c = \frac{r\,w + (r/2)\,a}{w+a} = \frac{(48*10 + 24*10)}{(10+10)} = 36 \,\mathrm{in} $

- Axial force of $f = a + w = 20 \,\mathrm{lb}$
- Overturning moment of $m = (a+w)*c/12 = 60 \,\mathrm{lb\,ft}$
- Radial force of $q = (a+w)*c*(n^2/35211.268) = 2.045\,\mathrm{lb}$

<sub>The magic number of $35211.268$ converts units around between pounds mass, inches, and rpm to give pounds-force.</sub>

Then you go to the motor specs and try to find information on the motor performance under those conditions.

---

This problem is an engineering problem, and as such you need to contact someone with an engineering background to solve this.

To illustrate my point here is free-body-diagram of the situation (with a change in nomenclature)

[image: fig1]

Comment: The formula for torque should be $$\tau = \frac{d}{2} ( f_{\rm top} + f_{\rm bot} )$$

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, with good bearings and maybe a counterweight, very little torque would be needed to maintain a constant angular velocity.  You need to be concerned about how you will control the speed (with gears, a drive belt, or a variable speed motor).